# "Entry Processes" constantly maxed and crashing my sites

Tags: cpanel

I'm so lost right now. I'm signed up with a shared web host, and for the past few days my sites have been fluctuating.

It's a shared host with 35/35 entry processes constantly maxed.

This started happening out of nowhere and my host is useless in helping me see which page/site is getting hammered.

I'm on cPanel and I looked at the visitors log and concurrent CPU usage logs.

I saw this process over and over in the CPU process logs whenever it crashes:

PID CMD CPU MEM

```
3596168 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  899
3596176 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  899
3631149 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  906
3642433 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  917
3669402 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  870
3669403 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  870
3669412 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  870
3671644 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  880
3671645 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  880
3672846 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  871
```

Am I looking in the right place? What else should I check? The downtime is really a nightmare and I can't sleep.

I have very limited technical knowledge and I'm on the brink of quitting my current host and signing up with another who have a "professional" DDoS firewall (and paying for it) just to get some help.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I always suggest using a quality web host. You may be better served switching. As to answering your question, I would have to think on this for a while. It has been a long time since I have seen sessions created that do not terminate properly. When Apache starts, it creates one instance and several cloned instances for standby. As requests come in, Apache can create more cloned instances as needed. It appears that your cloned instances are not terminating as they should. It could be the HTTP request at fault. Changing to a better host may help this. Cheers!!